# Save track in spotify with apple script or automator?

Tags: macos, applescript, spotify, automator

I would like to be able to save the selected track to a specific playlist with hotkeys OR just to "my  music". I've tried better touch tool but they don´t compile well with eachother. Is there a way to do this with apple script?

My thought was this: hotkey = right click > down arrow > down arrow > enter press. This would save the selecter track. I´ve found the keycodes for the arrow keys, but cant seem to find it for right click?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

No, Spotify's AppleScript interface doesn't contain functionality for modifying a user's playlists or saved songs.

You could use the Spotify Web API to achieve this, but you'll to have your users log in separately from the Spotify app.

Comment: Thats to bad. However I do have applescript combined with automator that if highlight a random text in chrome. Press a hotkey it automaticly opens spotify and search for the selected text. How come that is working? And there was "some" success with better touch tool, extremely buggy. But it did work in 1/20 times.